# How to watch disk free space change on Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-space

As the title implies, I want to know how to watch disk free space change on Linux instead polling it periodically via statfs. When the free space is changed, a signal is emitted to allow the application having a chance to handle the change event.

On Windows, it can be done by FindFirstChangeNotification with FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE. When the free space is changed, the HANDLE object returend by FindFirstChangeNotification gets signaled and let application do something.

Is there any similar way to do that on Linux? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same, but you could use [`inotify`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) with `IN_MODIFY`.

Comment: But inotify can not watch the directory recursively. Suppose the /dev/sda1 is mounted at /home, the changes in the sub-directories of /home can not trigger inotify which is watching /hoem.